# What is the scope of pre-compiler define in c++?

Tags: c++, precompile

Is the scope of the pre-compiler define the file where it defined?
for example:

three files :

test1.hpp/test1.cpp
test2.hpp/test2.cpp
test3.hpp/test3.cpp

An within test1.cpp:

```
#ifndef test1_hpp
#define test1_hpp

// some declarations

#endif
```

`test2.hpp` and `test.hpp` both `#include` test1.hpp. If the scope of test1_hpp is the whole application, as far as I understand, there can only one include test1.hpp success. Because once included, test1_hpp is defined.

Comment: "scoop" => "scope"? Also, make sure you mark code as code (indent with 4 spaces).

Comment: Please give a concrete **example** of the kind of variable you're talking about.

Comment: `An within test1.cpp:` You mean `test1.**hpp*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> test2.hpp and test.hpp both #include test1.hpp. If the scope of test1_hpp is the whole application, as far as I understand, there can only one include test1.hpp success. Because once included, test1_hpp is defined.

The compiler works on *translation units* (think: individual .cpp files) not the whole application (think: executable). What you call "the scope of the pre-compiler define" is the current *translation unit*. In your example, the `// some declarations` part in `test1.hpp` would be visible/processed in each of the CPPs that include `test1.hpp` directly or indirectly i.e. in all of `test1.cpp` (directly), `test2.cpp`, `test3.cpp` (indirectly, via `both #include test1.hpp`).

The `#ifndef test1_hpp` is a common idiom to prevent inadvertent inclusion of the same header file multiple times *within the same* translation unit - see for example ["Use of #include guards" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard#Use_of_.23include_guards).

Comment: I am sorry. I do not get it. The purpose c++ retain header guards precompilie is to avoid adding the declaration again. I have no duobt about this situation.It is the other secene that two different file both include one header once,If the variable defined by #define has global scope, The code will not excute on the other file because the variable has defined.The actual result is I can use in both files, but I do not know how that happens.

Comment: @malin.llvision `It is the other secene that two different file both include one header once,If the variable` Sorry, not sure what you mean by that. A macro #define'd while compiling file1.cpp has no effect whatsoever on the compilation of file2.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct. If you use the `#ifndef` guard in your header, the first time that test1.hpp is included in your application by the pre-processor, `test1_hpp` will be defined and will allow the inclusion of the code in your header. In future includes of test1.hpp, the code won't be re-included thanks to the guard.

This is needed, in most part, to prevent double definitions upon including the header in multiple files of your project, and comply with the [one definition rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).

Comment: In the first place ,thank you very much.
If the second time when #Include "test1.hpp" will not excute, how did the others get the interface?